# Contact Creation from Forms: web to contact

Tags: marketing-cloud

Currently creating forms through cloud pages that I want to also be able to create contacts in Sales Cloud. I've used web to lead to accomplish this for lead forms, but is there a best way to handle contact creation from forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it.

If at all, then create Leads with a certain flag, which you can then use to setup a workflow in Sales Cloud to directly convert the respective Leads to a Contact as soon as possible.

Reasoning:

Lead requires: Lastname and Company 
Contact requires: Lastname / account reference (You don't want orphan contacts.)

While "company" field on the lead is a text field and thus relatively open for user input, when creating a Contact, your form needs to know the Account ID, to reference the actual account in a lookup relationship.

This gets easier when using Personaccounts, where you always create Account + Contact as pairs.
In other scenarios, you don't want the form to create two accounts, just because one user entered "company,llc" and the other "company".

The lead >> contact conversion process inside Sales Cloud covers this account de-deduplication a lot better than your form could do (with a lot of custom code), as these could be relatively fuzzy matches, and sometimes choices required by the admin.

Fuzzy logic aside, to create contacts in a sustainable way under these circumstances, your page for would need to run multiple "retrieveSalesforceObject" calls to look for existing contacts AND existing accounts, slowing the page load time considerably.